# What is most preferred method to play video and audio on mobile website?

Tags: android, html, mobile-safari, mobile-website, html5-video

What is most preferred method to play video and audio on mobile websites?

I want to know if I'm having and Video and an MP3 file then how to convert them and embed in a webpage which is a page of mobile website.

Answer (score 1):

I think you know the answer to that already since you're tagging this as HTML5!

Use the [audio](http://www.html5laboratory.com/playing-with-audio-files.php) and [video](http://www.html5laboratory.com/using-the-video-element.php) elements. Use a fallback to Flash if you so wish.

Comment: No I don't need Flash fallback if HTML 5 audio video will work fine in Web-kit based browser. I'm only considering latest smartphones.

Comment: So javascript, jquery and Flash playersupport is not necessary to run video on HTML 5 supported browsers, right?

Comment: Well then my answer stands. That said, I don't have any statistics on phones and their support for HTML5 audio and video.